# Error in json parsing- zend framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, zend-framework, parsing

I want to make delete action asynchronous using AJAX, in the controller I make an action that handle the request

```
  public function deleteAction() {

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request) {
        $visitId = $request->getParam('visit_id');
        $mapper = new Visits_Model_VisitsMapper();
        try {
            $mapper->deleteVisit($visitId);
           echo json_encode("1");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->view->message = "error inserting Data, Error details: " . $e->getMessage();
          echo  json_encode("0");
        }

        Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setParam('noViewRenderer', true);
    }
}
```

and in the jquery script

```
 $("a.delete").live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var data={
                "visit_id":$(this).parent().parent().attr("id")
     };

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/visits/visit/delete",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: requestDate,
        success: successCallback,
        error:failureCallback
   });
```

When I click on delete button, the request is sent and an error on pop up occur

```
 Error    <!-- application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml -->
 the  whole html of layout page....
 error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

I detect that the delete process does not happened!! 
When I send synchronous request the delete operation happened successfully. And also when I make the AJAX call without using Layout page the delete is succeeded successfully also.

What can be the error?

Comment: `dataType: 'jsonp',` change that and give it another go ... usually fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your layout is rendered and then is getting parsed (unsuccessfully) by the jQuery code. Try turning it off:

```
try {
    $mapper->deleteVisit($visitId);
    if ($this->getRequest->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $this->_helper->json("1"); //this will disable layout and view renderer
                                   //and echo your data
    }
    else {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a simple error to track, just read carefully what file and line the error is on